# No way to pass data using form with Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

sorry if I am being redundant but I've tried every single example I found here and on google :D

What I am trying to do is on the upload of image, what was typed on inputbox will be send along to the uplodify.php where my insert is. My problem is, name of picture has being saved to the mysql but what was typed on the textfield  dont.

Would you  guys let me know what is going on?

This is the part of my code

```
'multi'                 : true,
'auto'                  : false,
'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
$("#file_upload").uploadify('settings', 'formData', {'galeria':  $('#galeria').val()});
}, 


<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">
  <p>
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Galeria<br>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="galeria" id="galeria">
```

uplodify.php

```
    $galeria = $_POST['galeria'];
    $regiao = $_POST['regiao'];

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $img      = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $ext      = substr($img, -4);
    $img      = md5($img).date("dmYHis").$ext;  
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
     $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $img;


    $adicionar = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO imagens (foto, galeria, regiao) VALUES('$img','$galeria','$regiao')");

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
    //  mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    // } else {
    //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
    // }
}
```

Comment: No one can help me on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your onUploadStart method to extend the uploadify formData property like this:

```
onUploadStart: function ( file ) {
  var $fileUpload = $('#file_upload')
      , formData = $fileUpload.uploadify('settings', 'formData')
      , newFormData = $.extend({}, formData, { galeria: $('#galeria').val() });

      $fileUpload.uploadify('settings', 'formData', newFormData);
}
```

Comment: TKS A LOT for the help... but still not working.. really dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is your php script receiving the "galeria" request parameter at all? I tested the above code and it does send through galeria parameter.
You might want to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag, and test the file upload without the uploadify script. To see if it's not something wrong with your php script.

Comment: Well... I downloaded the last version on uplodify and now I cant even made it work since pictures do not go to the folder... Will made it work and then use your code.. tks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to made it work

This is the code I used

```
    $('#file_upload').attr('file_upload', response).show();
$.post("insert2.php",{name: fileObj.name, galeria: $("#galeria").val(), regiao: $("#regiao").val()}, function(info) {
alert(info); // alert UPLOADED FILE NAME
        });
    }
});
```

Now I have a different problem lol it always show right...

Since the code to save the file on dabase is on insert2.php and the code to rename the picture inside the uploadify.php. How can I save the new name on the database instead the name of file I uploaded?

Another question.... is that a way to generate a thumbnail based on those pictures on database?